# What are the arguments of jQuery Deferred callbacks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

In jQuery, [deferred.then](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) adds handlers to be called when the Deferred object is resolved or rejected.

```
deferred.then( doneCallbacks, failCallbacks )
```

- **doneCallbacks** — A function, or array of functions, called when the Deferred is resolved.
- **failCallbacks** — A function, or array of functions, called when the Deferred is rejected.

What are arguments of these 'done' and 'fail' callback functions in the following example?

Does it depend on the type of Deferred object? For example:

```
$.when({testing: 123})
  .then(function(x){ ... }); 

$.when($.getJSON('foo'))
  .then(function(x){ ... });
```

will have different values for 'x'?

Comment: This isn't a direct answer, but something you can do is inspect the "arguments" keyword either with console.log or debugging, to see what all parameters are being passed and what their values are.  This is a useful practice when you're using new jQuery features that aren't yet documented (like what "e" is in virtually every jQuery mobile event).

Comment: Great question! I was just hunting the documentation for this myself!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done fallbacks and fail fallbacks are invoked by the creator of the `Deferred` calling [`resolveWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.resolveWith/) and [`rejectWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.rejectWith/), respectively; the two arguments these functions take are passed to the callback. So it depends entirely on the type of the function that created the `Deferred` object. (Context is usually but not necessarily the `Deferred` object itself.)

Comment: @Tgr: Did you mean to say "fallbacks" or should those say "callbacks"?